# Node js redis using child_process to manage queue windows process

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, child-process, bull

I have a question about redis using node js, my idea is to create an Orchestrator for my RPA (Robotic Process Automation) bots with a dashboard using websocket, I would like to know if it is right to command the queues using redis with bull and at the same time using child_process from node js to run the bots processes on my machine, or is there any other library that does this?

Sorry if its confuse